# C++: combine const with template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, constants, const-correctness, c++-templates

The following example is working when I manualy replace `T` wirh `char *`, but why is not working as it is:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
  public:
    A(const T _t) { }
};

int main(){
  const char * c = "asdf";
  A<char *> a(c);
}
```

When compiling with gcc, I get this error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:10: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
test.cpp:10: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'A<T>::A(T) [with T = char*]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting to const T&. Also, in these cases, you should let the compiler automatically deduce the template argument, and not specify it.

Answer (score 10):

Substituting `T` with `char*` gives a `const` pointer to char, while `c` is declared as a pointer to `const char`.

A solution would be to take pointers and integral types by value and class types by const reference. If you can, use [Boost Call Traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) which solves these kinds of problems for you.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because your function expects `const (char *)` (since T is `char *`), i.e. you can't change the address it points to, while `const char *` stands for `(const char) *`, i.e. you can't change the value on the place the pointer points to.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that the compiler knows that your template is instantiated with `T = char*` and first of all tries to see if the value you provide (`c`) is a `char*` (it is not; it's a `const char*`) *before* checking its const-ness.

Therefore you need to either:

1. `const_cast` the value `c`
2. Specify `A<const char *> a(c);`
3. Remove the `const` specifier from the declaration of A's constructor

The best of these to do is #3. This will lose you what I assume is a "guarantee" you need: that the value used to initialize objects of class A is constant. To achieve this again, you will have to use some implementation of [type traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/category/value_traits/properties.html) and [template constraints](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#constraints) to ensure that the template cannot be instantiated when T is not a `const` type.

Comment: Don't `const_cast` pointers to `const` data unless your requirements include undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

If you eliminate the const before c's assigning, the program will compile.

What's happening is that the constructor is not necessarily taking a const version of an instance. const is telling the constructor that you cannot change the data in T _t, which is not actually a const object within the scope of the constructor... it's a very subtle but important distinction to make.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your constructor `A(const char* _t)`, you're getting effectively `A( (const char) *t)`.  That is, a pointer to const char.  But when you specify `char*` as the template parameter, you're getting effectively `A( const (char *t))`, or a const pointer to char.

In other words, I think you have the same problem discussed in the article [A Midsummer Night's Madness](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403835), except with template parameters instead of typedefs.