# Why can't I pass a const object in a const argument function/method?

Tags: c++, constants

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I'm trying to understand a sample of code, which uses `QList::indexOf` method, declared as in [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qlist.html#indexOf).

Actually I'm trying to figure out why I need to use `const_cast` in this specific case:

```
int ProjTreeItem::row() const
{
    if (parentItem) {
            // instance of const object to test  
        const ProjTreeItem *item = new ProjTreeItem(QList<QVariant>(), NULL); 
            // Called indexOf here to test
        parentItem->childItems.indexOf(item); 
            // This works fine
        return parentItem->childItems.indexOf(const_cast<ProjTreeItem*>(this)); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2:**

I was looking at the wrong places, then I started to suspect that the issue had to do with the use of templates and the `const` modifier. I found this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822965/c-combine-const-with-template-arguments). Please, look at Jon 's answer, which I think clarifies the point I reached. Sorry for the misleadings on my question.

Comment: It should work fine. Since cbranch correctly pointed out a syntax error, and your posted code has no errors, it's clear you have some *real* code that's giving you problems. Instead of conjuring up fake hypothetical code, just narrow down the problem in yours and show us that, so we can solve a real problem instead of a hypothetical one.

Comment: It seems strange that you invoke a seemingly static method, but declare it `const` as well.  You aren't showing us something....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean the line

```
parentItem->childItems.indexOf(item);
```

doesn't compile.
I also presume you wrote

```
QList< ProjTreeItem* > childItems;
```

in `parentItem`'s type(class) definition.
If I understand correctly, in the line

```
parentItem->childItems.indexOf(item)
```

you are going to convert `ProjTreeItem const*` into `ProjTreeItem*`, and
this requires `const_cast`.
JaredC has already answered kindly about constness.
I suggest reading his answer again carefully.

**Edit:**
I think Jon's answer applies to your question.
The 1st parameter of `QList::indexOf` is `T const&`, where T is `ProjTreeItem*`
in your case.
So, the concrete parameter type is `ProjTreeItem*const&`.
Please note it differs from `ProjTreeItem const*const&`.
`ProjTreeItem*` and `ProjTreeItem const*` are different types.
`const_cast` is needed to convert from the latter to the former.
`ProjTreeItem const*` means that `ProjTreeItem` is `const`.
However, `ProjTreeItem*const&` means **pointer** is `const`, `ProjTreeItem` is **not** `const`.

**Edit2**:
You seem to misunderstand.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ProjTreeItem;

template< class T >
struct Test {
  typedef T const type;
};

int main()
{
  cout<< boolalpha;
  cout<<
    (typeid( Test< ProjTreeItem* >::type ) == typeid( ProjTreeItem const* ))
  <<endl;
  cout<<
    (typeid( Test< ProjTreeItem* >::type ) == typeid( ProjTreeItem*const ))
  <<endl;
}
```

If your interpretation is right, the above code will print `true`,
and then `false`.
However, the code prints `false`, and then `true`.

Comment: @Ise Wisteria your assumptions are correct. I do read it carefully, do appreciated a lot, as I stated there. I'm very grateful. But, I don't know at all if it answers exactly. At least I didnt get it. I reread it. I think its something to do with templates. I will create another thread and show an example where I suppose, clarifies better my question. Indeed, my question may be misleading.

Comment: What came about to be the point of the problem/doubt, I found a possible explanation at the following question (please, read Jon 's answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822965/c-combine-const-with-template-arguments

Comment: @Ise Wisteria: You said the 1st parameter is of type T const & but isn't it actually const T &?

Comment: @kaneda: No, T const& and const T& are identical.

Comment: @Ise Wisteria: If T = ProjTreeItem*, then `T const&` would be `ProjTreeItem* const&`, meaning a const-pointer-to-ProjTreeItem-object, but `const T&` would be in that case, equals to `const ProjTreeItem*&`, meaning a pointer-to-a-const-ProjTreeItem-object? Is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: @Ise Wisteria: I see. Things are more clear now. Thank you very much. I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think you wanted this instead:

```
void SomeClass::f(const MyClass*) const
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm works for me with this code:

```
class MyClass
{
};

class SomeClass 
{
public:
    void f(const MyClass *t) const
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass s;

    const MyClass *myClass = new MyClass;
    MyClass *myClass2 = new MyClass;

    s.f(myClass);
    s.f(myClass2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making the wrong assumption that the type of `item` is equal to the type of `this`, and I believe this is confusing you.

Inside a `const` function, the type of `this` is `ProjTreeItem const * const item`.  But your pointer that works is declared `const ProjTreeItem * item`:

```
// `this` is a constant-pointer-to-a-constant-ProjTreeItem
ProjTreeItem const * const this;   // obviously not valid code, just illustrating type

// `item` is simply a pointer-to-a-constant-ProjTreeItem
const ProjTreeItem * item;
```

It helps to read the declaration right to left.

So, declare you item pointer like this and I suspect you'll need a cast as well.

```
const ProjTreeItem * const item = new ProjTreeItem(QList<QVariant>(), NULL);
```

Comment: thank you much for the explanation. I learned a few more things reading on. But, in fact, my pointer const ProjTreeItem * item does not work, it needs to be const_casted or the compiler fails. What do work is const_casting the pointer or declaring the pointer without const. The indexOf method from QList accepts the argument type indexOf(const T & value), being T a template type, so T equals to ProjTreeItem *.